# How to replace the column values with respect to index in each iteration.So that each table will be having new set of values in each iteration

Tags: python, dataframe

Can anyone help me with this.

```
   Index      word
0      0         I
1      1        am
2      2        so
3      3      good
4      4       and
5      5     smart  

 df_series=[]
 for d in range(0,2):
    df_series.append(df)

def pos(x):
    position=[]
    for u in x:
        position.append(np.random.choice(u[0]))
    return position

 two = [5,2]
 j = [1,0]
 df1=[]
 df1.append(pd.DataFrame(two))
 df1.append(pd.DataFrame(j))
```

df1

```
   0
0  5
1  2
   0
0  1
1  0

 final=[] 
 L=['NA','****']
 for eachtable in df_series:
 #  print(eachtable)
    eachtable.loc[pos(df1),'word'] = random.choice(L)
    final.append(eachtable)
```

`final`

```
 Index  word
       0    ****
       1    NA
       2    so
       3    good
       4    and
       5    NA

    Index   word
       0    ****
       1    NA
       2    so
       3    good
       4    and
       5    NA
```

As of now I am getting like this only.Position is changing only for first table and repeating the same position for all the iteration.I want to changed position for each iteration. Can anyone find the mistake in my code and help me with this.

I want like something like this

`print(final)`

```
Index   word
   0    ****
   1    NA
   2    so
   3    good
   4    and
   5    NA
Index   word
   0    I
   1    am
   2    ****
   3    good
   4    NA
   5    smart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in first loop, in list is still referencing same `DataFrame` (`Series`):

```
for eachtable in df_series:
    print (id(eachtable))
294921776
294921776
```

Solution is add [`copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df_series=[]
for d in range(0,2):
    df_series.append(df.copy())
```

Check:

```
for eachtable in df_series:
    print (id(eachtable))
294987928
294922056

for eachtable in df_series:
    eachtable.loc[pos(df1),'word'] = random.choice(L)
    final.append(eachtable)

print (final)
[   Index   word
0      0     NA
1      1     am
2      2     NA
3      3   good
4      4    and
5      5  smart,    Index  word
0      0     I
1      1  ****
2      2    so
3      3  good
4      4   and
5      5  ****]
```